# Open Chrome but just get data in URL address want it to be google.com

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

This is the code I use:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com")
```

The URL I get in Google is data; I have selenium installed and Chromium. I don't know if I missed something. I tried with get driver a lot and it doesn't work.

Comment: try using `driver.get("http://www.google.com")`

Comment: I tried with get driver a lot and it doesn't work.

Comment: what means "doesn't work" ? Do you get error message ? then show it in question (not in comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: This can't be true, please try once again. I have written a lot of scripts with selenium and all of them access url with: from selenium import webdriver driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/User/Desktop/chromedriver.exe') driver.get(url)

Comment: one more clue that I have is that maybe you use outdated version of chromedriver. Please try to download the latest one from here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: and i should place the cromedriver in the folder where crome is?

Comment: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.27/chromedriver_win32.zip this one. There's no need to place it to your browser Chrome, they are not connected in any way. You can leave it anywhere